# RenderAction equivalent in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

[RenderPartial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.renderpartialextensions.renderpartial%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and [RenderAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.renderaction%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) are two methods in ASP.NET MVC used to render partial views. The difference is that the latter enables us to run some logic before the rendering takes place (and passing processed data to the partial view).

My question is: 
What is the equivalent of the RenderAction (the one with logic) in Zend Framework? 
And if Zend does not support this, what's the best solution to achieve similar functionality?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In ZF1, there are two view helpers that are equivalent :

[Action Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.action)

and

[Partial Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.partial)

I will not detail because the documentation is quite clear ;)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't specify which version of Zend I'm using. It's 2.0. I had no idea they've changed the framework so much. The method above is not presetn in ZF 2.0. [Here](http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2012/10/06/how-to-replace-the-action-helper-in-zf-2-and-make-great-widgetized-content/)'s a workaround.